# Import seaborn error: cannot import name 'cov'

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn

Recently updated all packages with conda. Tried to import seaborn and had this:

```
------
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py in <module>()
     27 from scipy import linalg, special
     28 from scipy.special import logsumexp
---> 29 from scipy._lib._numpy_compat import cov
     30 from scipy._lib._util import check_random_state
     31 

ImportError: cannot import name 'cov'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What versions of Seaborn, and especially, SciPy does Conda say it is now using? That is, what is the output of `conda list`?

Comment: Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: upd. conda list: 
scipy                     1.0.0; 
seaborn                   0.10.0; 
python                    3.6.10.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update your SciPy version: 1.0.0 is from October 2017, and the current version is 1.4.1. It looks like Conda failed to update SciPy properly:

```
conda update scipy
```

In fact, when I create a Conda environment with your listed version numbers, I get the following conflict notice:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
Package scipy conflicts for:
scipy=1.0.0
seaborn=0.10.0 -> scipy[version='>=1.0.1']
```

which indicates that this problem is known, and was probably fixed in SciPy 1.0.1. Better to just use SciPy version 1.4.1 though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Comment: @matuhaerys And, any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue.

As far as I can tell there is no such function referenced in either the KDE.py file or the Scipy documentation. As such, I removed the import in the KDE.py file and everything's been working so far, so I figure that's your best bet.